# Failed to run an application into Simulator like iPhone-Linker command failed with Exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, xcode7.3, sup

I am developing applications using Objective C as front end , SUP as middleware and SAP as backend

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBOLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CallbackHandler.o
      objc-class-ref in AnonymousCallbackHandler.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractDBRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBGraybarMobilityDB in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBGraybarMobilityDB.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBAnonGraybarMobilityAnonymousDB in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBAnonGraybarMobilityAnonymousDB.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractEntityRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBCustomAddress in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBCustomAddress.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBPackageProperties in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBPackageProperties.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBOrder_Delivery_Line_Item in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBOrder_Delivery_Line_Item.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBContactMethod in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBContactMethod.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBAnonLogRecordImpl in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBAnonLogRecordImpl.o)
      objc-class-ref in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBAnonLogRecordImpl.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GBFavoriteList in libgeneratedcode_lib.a(GBFavoriteList.o)
```

my problem is when I am running my application on iPhone Simulator which is having connection to the middleware and using SUP libraries,it is showing build failed 'Linker command failed with Exit code 1'
My Xcode version is 7.3 ,simulator is 9.3 iPhone 4s.I am using SUP Object API version 2.3.7

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems related to `Linker command failed with Exit code 1` Anyway you can try one of these solutions:

- 1. Make sure your deployment target is either the version of your code;
     [image]
- 2. You can get this problem by declaring a `const * NSString` in the header file .h (wrong) instead of in the implementation file .m (correct);
- 3. Also you can get this issue if accidentally you imported a `.m` file instead of the `.h`
- 4. Or Go to Targets (Project Name) -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources see if it's missing a `.m` file and add it
- 5. Or Go to Targets (Project Name) -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources see if there is a duplicated file and delete it.
- 6. Or Try to set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` for 'Pods' project and your app's target

After do any of these solutions do a **cmd+shift+k** to clean the project and try `run` it again.

I hope this can help you.